# What could be causing my app google engine cron job not to work?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I've the following in cron.xml on my WEB-INF directory:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>

  <cron>
    <url>/?brtyuioacdwer</url>
    <description>Load datastore</description>
    <schedule>every monday 06:17</schedule>
    <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

But when the time comes to execute the shown URL nothing seems to happen as my datastore keeps the same, of course I've tested to call the URL from browser and it does its work nicely and I've uploaded new version of the app several minutes before it should be automatically executing. I don't know if there might be some problems with cron jobs when they try to write on datastore or if they are not the default version af the web application, so I'm asking for some guide.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Does your code get executed if you invoke `/?brtyuioacdwer` by hand (in browser)?

Comment: Yes, it does execute.

Comment: If your cron jobs are getting called, you should see them in your admin logs.  It's very likely, there might be something in your cron handler that's failing.  Otherwise, it could be something in cron.xml.  Your cron.xml looks right, but I'm not sure if the ? character in the url might cause problems.